# while: command not found

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I'm trying to do this as an April Fool's prank: make a linux machine display a message in the shell every few seconds.

My thought is to achieve this by starting an infinite loop that runs as a background job (in .bashrc).

For example, this does what I want:

```
while true ; do echo Evil Message; sleep 10; done
```

In order to run it in background I tried:

```
cmd="while true ; do echo Evil Message; sleep 10;"
$cmd &
```

but this fails with the error:

```
while: command not found
```

Why do I get the error? Is there a way to make this script work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`while` is not a command, it's a shell keyword. Keywords are recognised before variable expansion happens, so after the expansion, it's too late.

You have several options:

1. Don't use a variable at all.

   ```
   while true ; do echo Evil Message; sleep 10; done &
   ```
2. Use `eval` to run the shell over the expanded value of the variable

   ```
   eval "$cmd" &
   ```
3. Invoke a shell to run the loop

   ```
   bash -c "$cmd" &
   ```
4. Use a function (that's what is typically used to store code):

   ```
   cmd() { while true ; do echo Evil Message; sleep 10; done; }
   cmd &
   ```

Comment: Bonus points  if you pipe the echo string to the wall command, all logged in users will get it in their tty ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Another option (besides all the good options listed in choroba's answer) would be to run it in a subshell, like this:

```
(while true; do echo Evil Message; sleep 10; done;) &
```

This will cause `bash` to run another instance of itself running your code, in the background.